# Index/Match for an entire table rather than a single column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, array

I am looking for a formula that will locate an exact match of a value somewhere within a table of given values.

Table d,e,f contains the differences between values in columns a and b, but that's not too important. I'm interested in finding the values in column g within this table d,e,f.

Please see the photo for reference.[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWmSd.png)

Column G contains four values that I want to locate in my table d,e,f. If the number in column G is found within the table, I want excel to output this number in column h. If this number is not within the table, I want either an error message or nothing at all to be inputted into its respective column h cell. (this is the case for 312,600 in the photo i've attached.)

I dont want to use a =vlookup() function because I will not necessarily know the column number in which said number is located. I want excel to scan the range of cells - d2:f13 - to look for this number in any of the columns.

I'm sure there is an index/match formula that will scan the range of cells d2:f13 to find the lookup value (those values in column G), but so far I can only get this function to scan one column at a time.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel INDEX MATCH Checking Multiple Columns](https://superuser.com/questions/1078152/excel-index-match-checking-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple `Range=value` expression wrapped in `SUM & IF` to manipulate the result. This is not `INDEX MATCH` combination that actually locates/looks up the value but a simple manipulation of Range=Value and return the same value if `TRUE`.

In this example sample data is in cells `D1:F8`. The lookup values are in cells `H2` thru `H8`.  Now in `I`2 put the following formula and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall now be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula.

```
=IF(SUM(IF($D$1:$F$8=H2,1,0))>=1,H2,"")
```

See the below screenshot. There could be a `SUMPRODUCT` alternative too if you don't wish to use Array Formula just in case.

[image]